# what is a YES/NO field type in access sql query?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, boolean

I want to add a YES/NO field **done** to a table **myTable** in MS Access by running a query in VBA.

my code is like this:

```
strSql = "ALTER TABLE myTable ADD COLUMN done Boolean"
doCmd.runSql strsql
```

I'm getting a **syntax error in field definition.**

I searched online what a Boolean field is in access and tried: `YES/NO`, `BOOL`, `dbBoolean` and `BIT`. Only `BIT` worked, but it's not giving me a YES/NO field, just a field that can be either 0 or 1.

Comment: According to http://allenbrowne.com/ser-49.html it's `YESNO`

Comment: To write/return Yes/No, you can use `IIF` function.

Comment: Try this: `ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN done YESNO;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a good reference: [Field type reference - names and values for DDL, DAO, and ADOX](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-49.html)

For Yes/No (boolean), the DDL name is `YESNO`, so it's

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD COLUMN done YESNO
```